# Когда локальный кэш потока сбрасываться в основную память

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация

```
public class App {
    static final float[] arr = new float[100];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; arr[i] = i, i++) ;
        });
        t1.start();
        t1.join();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Основной поток ожидает завершения потока t1. Верно ли, что после этого, изменения внесённые потоком t1 в arr будут всегда видны в основном потоке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html

> When a thread terminates and causes a Thread.join in another thread to return, then all the statements executed by the terminated thread have a happens-before relationship with all the statements following the successful join. The effects of the code in the thread are now visible to the thread that performed the join.

В Java не оперируют "сбрасыванием кеша в основную память". Тут работает принцип ["A happens-before B"](https://habr.com/ru/post/133981/).

И в цитате как раз и сказано, что если один поток завершается, а другой вызывает join для него, то все, что завершающийся поток выполнил (записал в память) будет теперь видно для потока, который позвал join для этого потока.

То есть, это говорит, только то, что эти два потока корректно "передадут данные". Если рядом ещё есть поток, который позвал join для 4 потока, то для него то, что произошло в первых двух потоках не работает.

P.S. У Вас в вопросе то **"Основной поток"**, то "**главном потоке"**. Если это один и тот же поток, то ответ на Ваш вопрос - да, все будет ок. Если же это разные потоки, то ответ "а кто его знает". Но по коду вроде все таки это один и тот же поток.

Comment: Исправил описание